# Using Ref as the first argument in Fn::Sub intrinsic function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I experience quite strange issues when compiling the template, where I reference a string parameter in `Fn::Sub`, while the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) do explicitly say that one can use `Ref` function inside of `Fn::Sub`. Here is a piece of template:

```
"Resources": {
    "LaunchConfiguration": {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties" : {
        "UserData": { "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Sub": { "Ref": "UserDataParam" } } },
```

And here is an error I get:

> Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify
>   expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an
>   optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in
>   the string

When I use full notation: `{ "Fn::Sub": [ { "Ref": "UserDataParam" }, {} ] }`, I get exactly the same error. Has anybody had the same issue? And is it possible to avoid it while still using the parameter?

Comment: I think this will be better served if migrated to ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

You are misreading the docs. While the docs do say you can use the `Ref` function, it is only in the second (optional) parameter (the key-value map) where you can do that.

The example given in the docs is:

```
{"Fn::Sub": ["www.${Domain}", {"Domain": {"Ref": "RootDomainName"}}]}
```

If, however, you need to substitute into the first parameter, you must use the dollar notation.

To achieve what you appear to want, you should rewrite your code as:

```
{"Fn::Sub": "${UserDataParam}"}
```

Or in context:

```
"UserData": {"Fn::Base64": {"Fn::Sub": "${UserDataParam}"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively it's possible to substitute directly without using a separate variable:

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Sub": "${myS3Bucket}"
  }
}
```

The key is to use `Fn::Sub` without the usual square brackets as explained at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=745085#745085

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use a Ref within a Fn::Sub function call. To achieve a value mapping, you first have to assign the Ref value into a local variable und use that one within the Fn::Sub string.

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Sub": [
      "${variable}",
      {
        "variable": {
          "Ref": "myS3Bucket"
        }
      }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this method it won't be substituting variables inside the "myS3Bucket", which I think it would be the primary goal of having it as `Sub` first argument.

Comment: The real problem is the OP wants to get the variable from a parameter, whereas this form of Sub takes the variable instead from the key-value map that is provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a bash script within your metadata and encountered this error, options 1 and 2 in my example code are valid but option 3 is not because **"- |"** tells the sub intrinsic function to expect another **"- |"** as shown in option 1, that should provide mapping of values (e.g ***- {A mapping of some sort}***) to replace strings inside ***{blablabla}***. When the second mapping is not found, the error is thrown.

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
   files:
   ##### use
    '/dir/subdir':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
        - {A mapping of some sort}
    ###### or 

    '/dir2/subdir2':
      content: !Sub |
          {blablabla}

    ##### But don't mix like so

    '/dir3/subdir3':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
```